Installing seadas9.1.0, stuck in "command line argument:"....what should i do?
While installing seadas in centos7, follow problems occur:
[server@localhost seadas_installer]$ ./seadas_9.1.0_linux64_installer.sh Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good. Uncompressing SeaDAS Application  100%

Command line arguments:
the program stuck here and a window named IzPack-Installation of SeaDas IzPack Installer shows, the window is filled red and has no button in it.
I've checked versions of python3, Java and bash that required for seadas, but still did not work.
Is the problem about IzPack? If it is possible that anyone could help me figure it out?
QAQ
Thank you very much
